# Calling Deep Nested Arrays

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have an expected JSON payload that is fairly deep in nested arrays/objects. As I am assigning variables based on the assumed structure

```
{
  id: value1,
  name: value2,
  data: {
    status: complete,
    date: 2020 - 06 - 20,
    notes: {
      field1: "user notes",
      field2: "more user notes"
    }
  }
}
```

In my code I will make a call like this:

```
var usernote = payload.data.notes.field1 || "No Notes"
```

But it may occur that the user raised no notes, so the notes object will return as undefined. Is there anyway around this without doing a set of cascading default checks? Some of my calls look like this:

```
priorityvar = payload.data.form_values["b691"][index]["form_values"]["d54d"]["choice_values"][0]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I couldn't find a similar answer in my search (but very new to here too). Also I am working in Google Apps Scripts so I cant use any ES6 stuff.

Comment: Apps script supports ES6, but not ES2020

Comment: @TheMaster Is there something I am missing here? [Link to GAS](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#modern_ecmascript_syntax) that link seems to suggest ES6 is not implemented yet?

Comment: Only ES6 "Modules" are not implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can think to avoid multiple checks (since you are using Google Apps Scripts and "*cant use any ES6 stuff*", is by using a `try catch` approach.

That will validate the whole expression for you, so you don't worry about individual key validations in your object:

```
var usernote;

try {
  usernote = payload.data.notes.field1;
} catch (error) {
  usernote = "No Notes";
}
```

---

### For people that can use newer technology

The new ECMA Script 2020 was just released last week and now **[optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)** is an official thing.

It allows you to do things like this and not worry if any of those values is `undefined`:

```
var usernote = payload?.data?.notes?.field1 || "No Notes"
```

From the documentation:

> The optional chaining operator permits reading the value of a property located deep within a chain of connected objects without having to expressly validate that each reference in the chain is valid

Comment: Thank you, this works. Unfortunately it isnt the cleanest solution as I have a lot of calls and very annoyed I cant use the much cleaner ECMA20 version!

Answer (score 1):

You can use lodash's `_.get(obj, path, defaultValue)` function. It will try to access the value inside an object that matches given path. Here some examples from [the offical documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/3.10.1#get).

```
var object = { 'a': [{ 'b': { 'c': 3 } }] };
 
_.get(object, 'a[0].b.c');
// => 3
 
_.get(object, ['a', '0', 'b', 'c']);
// => 3
 
_.get(object, 'a.b.c', 'default');
// => 'default'
```

If you cannot import lodash, try to implement one.

Comment: this looks like a good solution but I havent started using libraries yet in GAS so will likely start, also no idea why but that link is in cantonese (I believe?) and english link [here](https://lodash.com/docs/3.10.1#get)